# Grouping data with in time range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a requirement to get a start time and end time in the condition where `val = 'Y'` and `col_val < 5`.

I have a table named temp_vvv structure like

```
date_time             |     val    |  col_val
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
03/06/2014 08:58:00         Y          4
03/06/2014 08:59:00         Y          3
03/06/2014 09:00:00         Y          1
03/06/2014 09:01:00         Y          0
03/06/2014 09:01:30         Y          0
03/06/2014 09:02:00         Y          2
03/06/2014 09:02:30         Y          5
03/06/2014 09:03:00         Y         20
03/06/2014 09:03:30         Y         50
03/06/2014 09:04:00         Y         55
03/06/2014 09:04:30         Y         60
03/06/2014 09:05:00         Y         10
03/06/2014 09:05:30         Y          4
03/06/2014 09:06:00         Y          2
03/06/2014 09:06:30         Y          0
03/06/2014 09:07:00         Y          0
03/06/2014 09:07:30         Y          1
03/06/2014 09:08:00         N          5
03/06/2014 09:08:30         N          0
```

I am expecting output like

```
  start_date_time       |     end_date_time
 --------------------------------------------------
 03/06/2014 08:58:00         03/06/2014 09:02:00
 03/06/2014 09:05:30         03/06/2014 09:07:30
```

How to get this output from a select query

Please help me.

**EDIT**

The value of col_val <5 is start from `'03/06/2014 08:58:00'` and ends at `'03/06/2014 09:02:00'` .so that first record is `start_date_time` is `'03/06/2014 08:58:00'` and `end_date_time` is `'03/06/2014 09:02:00'` and so on .

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to group the records based on `COL` and `COL_VAL`.

Try with the below query,

```
SELECT MIN(date_time) start_date_time, MAX(date_Time) end_date_time
FROM(
    SELECT date_time, val, col_val, CASE WHEN val = 'Y' AND col_val < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END col_val_limit,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TIME) - 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN val = 'Y' AND col_val < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY DATE_tIME) grp
    FROM    temp_vw
    )
WHERE  col_val_limit = 1
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY start_date_time;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  min(date_time),
  max(date_time)
from (
  select
    date_time,
    sum(new_group) over (order by date_time) group_
  from (
    select
      date_time,
      val,
      col_val,
      case when
        case when lag(val    ) over (order by date_time) = 'Y' and
                  lag(col_val) over (order by date_time) <  5  then
             1
        else 0 end 
        !=
        case when val = 'Y' and
                  col_val < 5 then
             1
        else 0 end
      then
        1
      else
        0
      end              new_group
    from
      tq84_t
  )
  where
    val = 'Y' and col_val < 5
)
group by group_;
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64545/1).

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but the idea is to identify the group each row belongs to by the group's starting time. The starting time is identified by getting the lowest dated valid row (val = 'Y' and col_val = '5') where no invalid row exists inbetween. Finally the rows are grouped by starting time and the end time is retrieved using `MAX`

```
SELECT min_time start_date_time, MAX(date_time) end_date_time
FROM (
    SELECT
    date_time,
    (
        SELECT MIN(date_time)
        FROM temp_vvv t2
        WHERE val = 'Y' AND col_val < 5
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_vvv t3
            WHERE t3.date_time BETWEEN t2.date_time AND t1.date_time
            AND (t3.val <> 'Y' OR t3.col_val >= 5)
        )
    ) min_time
    FROM temp_vvv t1
    WHERE t1.val = 'Y'
    AND t1.col_val < 5
) GROUP BY min_time
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64545/8

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am expecting out put not like this.

Comment: @Taniya can you try again? the equality sign was wrong `OR t3col_val >= 5` (thanks to Rene for the fiddle!)